# Make AWS s3 directory public using php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know there is no concept of folders in S3, it uses a flat file structure. However, i will use the term "folder" for the sake of simplicity.

**Preconditions:**

- An s3 bucket called foo
- The folder foo has been made public using the AWS Management Console
- Apache
- PHP 5
- Standard AWS SDK

**The problem:**

It's possible to upload a folder using the AWS PHP SDK. However, the folder is then only accessible by the user that uploaded the folder and not public readable as i would like it to be.

**Procedure:**

```
$sharedConfig = [
    'region'  => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'visibility' => 'public',
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => 'xxxxxx',
        'secret' => 'xxxxxx',
    ],
];

// Create an SDK class used to share configuration across clients.
$sdk = new Aws\Sdk($sharedConfig);

// Create an Amazon S3 client using the shared configuration data.
$client = $sdk->createS3();

$client->uploadDirectory("foo", "bucket", "foo", array(
            'params'      => array('ACL' => 'public-read'),
            'concurrency' => 20,
            'debug'       => true
        ));
```

**Success Criteria:**

I would be able to access a file in the uploaded folder using a "static" link. Fx:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket/foo/001.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by using a defined "Before Execute" function.

```
  $result = $client->uploadDirectory("foo", "bucket", "foo", array(
            'concurrency' => 20,
            'debug'       => true,
            'before' => function (\Aws\Command $command) {
            $command['ACL'] = strpos($command['Key'], 'CONFIDENTIAL') === false
                ? 'public-read'
                : 'private';
        }

        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use this:

```
$s3->uploadDirectory('images', 'bucket', 'prefix',
            ['params' => array('ACL' => 'public-read')]
        );
```